# What wiring issues am I looking at for engine swap?

Tags: engine, gmc, sierra, swap

Thinking of putting 2003 Chevrolet Trailblazer 4.2 L engine in 1981 GMC Sierra. Complete 2003 Trailblazer donor vehicle. 1981 GMC has a small block 305 and 3.42 rear-end. What wiring issues will I incur swapping the engine over? Any other concerns?